# Why doesn't this UIViewController receive my NSNotification

Tags: iphone, label, nsnotificationcenter

I am having trouble getting a viewController to receive notifications from NSNotificationCenter. Where am I going wrong?

In my viewController, I have defined :

```
- (id)init {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(receiveEvent:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
                                               object:nil];


    return self;
}


- (void)receiveEvent:(NSNotification *)notification {
    counter = counter + 1;
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", counter];  
    vocabword.text = string;
}
```

But the text is not updating :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your init method being called?  (and, why aren't you calling [super init] in there?)

Depending on how you construct your viewController, the init method itself may not be called.  Rather, anther initializer might be used, such as initWithCoder: if being loaded from a xib.

Typically I'll register for notifications in viewDidLoad and unregister in viewDidUnload.  Is there a reason you'd need to receive the notification if your view were unloaded for some reason (e.g. too much memory pressure?)

Comment: ya exactly, the init is not being called. how do i fix that? i need the viewcontroller to do something each time the app resigns active, so idk how to do that using viewDidLoad and viewDidUnload. Does the view unload each time the user puts the device to sleep?

Comment: Got it!!!! After days of struggling with it, I got it! I put the code in -(id)init in - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil instead

Comment: The view doesnt necessarily unload each time the user exits the app (it could, if iOS decided to unload it, however).  I was only suggesting viewDidLoad/viewDidUnload are good places to register/unregister for notfications, vs. init/dealloc.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in the code you posted is obviously wrong.  It's probably some other problem.  Are you getting the log message?  Are you sure your class is being created?  Are you actually resigning active on the application?

Comment: Nope nothing is showing up in NSLog. And what do you mean by resigning active? In dealloc, I have this: [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];